# span tag inside a dynamically generated td - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dynamically generated page of an enterprise application. The data is inside table structure. I need to access a value of span tag inside this table.

The page code looks like

```
<td class="dCCItemValue" valign="bottom>
<span id="S_0_1_5">Problem type</span>
```

The id of the span tag is also generated dynamically and I have no control over it.
So the problem statement becomes:
How to get value span inside a td with class "dCCItemValue"

I hope I have explained the problem correctly. Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the descendant operator (space) in the selector:

```
var value = $('.dCCItemValue span').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
$('.dCCItemValue').children('span').text()
```